# Trouble with input

Tags: c++, string, validation

My input file consists of 2 lines which have numbers separated by spaces. I have to read numbers from both lines and store them in 2 different `std::vector`s. But I don't know how many numbers are there in each line. How do I ensure that while reading the first line I don't start reading the numbers of second line also? I tried reading them as strings and checking for "`\n`" character but it doesn't work....

```
    cin>>str;
    while(str[0]!='\n' && str!="") {
        sscanf(str.c_str(),"%d",&num); 
        numz.push_back(num); //numz is the vector for the first line of numbers
        cin>>str;
    }
```

Is there some neat way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following reads a line into a vector. Of course you should add error checking.

```
std::vector<int> readnumline(std::istream& is)
{
  std::string line;
  std::getline(is, line);
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  int num;
  std::vector<int> result;
  while(iss >> num)
    result.push_back(num);
  return result;
}
```

To read two vectors, you can then use

```
std::vector<int> v1(readnumline(std::cin));
std::vector<int> v2(readnumline(std::cin));
```

Comment: It all started so well..., but the actual read into the vectors can be simplified a bit (or at least the loop removed from the code): `/* ... */ std::istringstream iss(line); return std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<>());`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: While that version is shorter, it's harder to add proper error handling to it (for example, you'll want to check that actually the complete line was consumed; you certainly don't want to put the parsing into the return statement). Also, I don't think a loop is something evil. And I'd certainly use `istream_iterator`s more often if they hadn't given them such a terribly long name ;-) (maybe they should have given templated `begin`/`end` to the streams, so you could write `iss.begin<int>()` and `iss.end<int>()`).

Comment: Not too long ago (two or three weeks) the possible addition of `begin`/`end` was discussed in the standard mailing list, in particular the intention was supporting range based iteration. It did not seem appropriate for that particular use case (where there is no template argument that can be passed) Not sure if there would be better acceptance for this templated approach, but I would be surprised if that is the case as it would be a new different thing.

Answer (score 3):

`#include <sstream>` to get access to `std::istringstream`.
Then the code should look like this:

```
std::string line1;
std::string line2;

std::getline(std::cin, line1);
std::getline(std::cin, line2);

int x;
std::vector<int> v;
std::istringstream iss(line1);
while (iss >> x) {
    v.push_back(x);
}
```

First we read the two lines using `getline`, then you create an `istringstream` object, and it works just like it was `std::cin`.

Comment: can you plz specify how can i get numbers from these? using strtok?